# How to install LKRG - Linux Kernel Runtime Guard on 18.04?

Tags: kernel, security

How to install this module, is there any ppa? or detailed instructions?

> [Linux Kernel Runtime Guard (LKRG)](https://www.openwall.com/lkrg/) is a loadable kernel module
>   that performs runtime integrity checking of the Linux kernel and
>   detection of security vulnerability exploits against the kernel. As
>   controversial as this concept is, LKRG attempts to post-detect and
>   hopefully promptly respond to unauthorized modifications to the
>   running Linux kernel (integrity checking) or to credentials (such as
>   user IDs) of the running processes (exploit detection). For process
>   credentials, LKRG attempts to detect the exploit and take action
>   before the kernel would grant the process access (such as open a file)
>   based on the unauthorized credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the sources:

```
$ wget https://www.openwall.com/signatures/openwall-offline-signatures.asc
$ gpg --import openwall-offline-signatures.asc
$ wget https://www.openwall.com/lkrg/lkrg-0.6.tar.gz.sign
$ wget https://www.openwall.com/lkrg/lkrg-0.6.tar.gz
$ gpg --verify lkrg-0.6.tar.gz.sign lkrg-0.6.tar.gz
```

Unpack:

```
$ tar -zxvf lkrg-0.6.tar.gz
$ cd lkrg-0.6/
```

Build:

```
$ make - j8
$ modinfo output/p_lkrg.ko
```

Run:

```
$ sudo insmod output/p_lkrg.ko p_init_log_level=3
```

Install systemd service and run it:

```
$ sudo make install
$ sudo systemctl start lkrg
```

Done!